# How do I install sasl2-bin dependencies?

Tags: 11.04, dependencies, sasl

I'm trying to install sasl2-bin on Natty. However, it depends on db4.8-util, which could not be installed because the default package on Natty is db4.7-util. If I try to install the 4.8 version either from the deb package or from source, it gets deeper into the dependency tree, i.e. it requires more packages to be updated. I did try to manually update them all but at one point (after updating libc-bin) it said I needed to update openssh but that will break a LOT of things for me.

On the other hand, without sasl, I can't run postfix. Could someone please help me resolve this dependency issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do,

`sudo apt-get install db4.8-util`

and then

`sudo apt-get install sasl2-bin`

Comment: sorry I was being stupid. At first I couldn't run that command but that was because of something entirely unrelated...